# OAuth-Based Authentication Scheme

Tags: c++, qt, oauth

I have an application that is run on multiple user systems, and using OAuth, allows the users to log in via Facebook, Twitter, etc. The entire point of the user logging in is to get settings and actions that the same user made while logged in on other computers, as identified by logging in with the same OAuth provider + provider user id. The application itself is written in C++ using Qt.

My question is this: how can I save the settings that a user made, and allow them to retrieve it in a secure way? I have a centralized server that I can store information using MySql tables, but I'm not sure the best way to have the user application prompt the server, and receive the data stored for that user.

Any ideas or places you could point me towards?

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: 5.1. The issue I have isn't on the application end; I have OAuth working in the application fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways I could think of with this, all have trade offs:

Generally I would store the data in mysql using some kind of string or object encryption/serialization method. I do not use Qt much but http://qt-project.org/wiki/Simple_encryption has some examples of very simple encryption that could be used.

Then the question becomes: What do you use as the key? I would go either with the key provided by OAuth for that user (which could be an issue if users de-authorize the app but still want access to this data) or some other user provided key (which is counter to using OAuth in the first place).

Another option is to go with Qt Users session http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-guide-cache.html

This would maybe remove the need to encrypt since it should only be accessible within the users scope.

NOTE: Based on comments below it seems the issue is more about securing communication with the MySQL versus the data inside of MySQL. Waiting on user comments to revise my answer.

Comment: Matt, I'm storing the data (user settings, etc) remotely in a centralized sql table. My problem isn't storing session information on the application users, but rather, figuring out how to transfer information between the OAuth'ed application user, and the non-OAuth'ed sever.

Comment: so your issue is needing to secure the transport between your app server and your database? That was confusing to me because that is pretty standard to either secure at the physical layer (Firewall) or logical layer (SSL) but there is always a notion of trust for your machine to access the RDBMS.

Comment: can you tell us a little more about your user IdAM? Will each user have their own username in the MySQL DB? If not will your Qt app manage the MySQL on behalf of all users?

Comment: The issue isn't in transport, but more of making sure the server only gives user data to the correct user. Lets say User A is logged in with his Facebook ID, which correlates to user number 10 in the server database. On User A's client, he's authenticated with an OAuth token. When User A logs in somewhere, his client requests the user information using his Facebook ID as an identifier. Now the problem is: how can I prevent User B from simply saying that he's User A, and getting/setting their data? If they have to log into my server, it sorta defeats the entire purpose of using OAuth.

Comment: Don't you have any notion of user session when the person logs in via oAuth? You still need to click "sign in" and it will bounce that request via the OAuth Provider right? Why can't you do a check against that session thats created when they login?

For example: When I login to StackOverflow I still click "sign in" (even though its with my google account). Even if its a saved session cookie wouldnt that still work?